# Install python-devel with yum

Tags: python, yum

I am trying to install `python-devel` with `yum` using:

```
sudo yum install python-devel
```

and getting the following:

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python-devel.x86_64 0:2.7.5-76.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python(x86-64) = 2.7.5-76.el7 for package: python-devel-2.7.5-76.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: python-devel-2.7.5-76.el7.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: python(x86-64) = 2.7.5-76.el7
           Installed: python-2.7.5-80.el7_6.x86_64 (@updates)
               python(x86-64) = 2.7.5-80.el7_6
           Available: python-2.7.5-68.el7.x86_64 (base)
               python(x86-64) = 2.7.5-68.el7
           Available: python-2.7.5-69.el7_5.x86_64 (updates)
               python(x86-64) = 2.7.5-69.el7_5
           Available: python-2.7.5-76.el7.x86_64 (base)
               python(x86-64) = 2.7.5-76.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

My understand is it requires this specific version of python: `python-2.7.5-76.el7.x86_64` and thus I tried:

```
sudo yum install python-2.7.5-76.el7.x86_64
```

However it output:

```
Package matching python-2.7.5-76.el7.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update.
Nothing to do
```

What should I do?

If I ran: `sudo yum info python`, it gave me:

```
Installed Packages
Name        : python
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.7.5
Release     : 80.el7_6
Size        : 79 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : updates
Summary     : An interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
URL         : http://www.python.org/
License     : Python
Description : Python is an interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming
            : language often compared to Tcl, Perl, Scheme or Java. Python includes
            : modules, classes, exceptions, very high level dynamic data types and
            : dynamic typing. Python supports interfaces to many system calls and
            : libraries, as well as to various windowing systems (X11, Motif, Tk,
            : Mac and MFC).
            : 
            : Programmers can write new built-in modules for Python in C or C++.
            : Python can be used as an extension language for applications that need
            : a programmable interface.
            : 
            : Note that documentation for Python is provided in the python-docs
            : package.
            : 
            : This package provides the "python" executable; most of the actual
            : implementation is within the "python-libs" package.
```

Comment: ```sudo yum downgrade <package_name>-<version_info>``` might  help. More info here : https://www.shellhacks.com/yum-install-specific-version-of-package/

Comment: Did you disable or remove the updates repo?

Comment: @jordanm What is the command for that?

Comment: @SANTOSHKUMARDESAI I tried what you said and got similar error says you need `python-libs(x86-64) = 2.7.5-76.el7`

Comment: Follow @user138278's solution and see if it works

Comment: @user3788685 I've updated my question

Comment: @EricHe you could try and disable the `base` repo and re-test. I've just installed on a test machine with no issues so I think something is a bit confused on your side.

Answer (score 5):

You can specify arch in suffix, this worked for me:

```
sudo yum install python3-devel.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the **resolvedep** subcommand to your invocation, which will have yum resolve dependencies if they exist and then you can yum install

```
yum resolvedep python-devel
yum install python-devel
```

Comment: Do you mean run `sudo yum resolvedep python-devel ` first and then run `sudo yum install python-devel`?

Comment: after I ran the first command it outputs: `python-devel:`
`0:python-devel-2.7.5-76.el7.x86_64 base` but then when I ran the second command it still gave me the same error

Answer (score 0):

rhel 7

yum --enablerepo=rhel-7-server-optional-rpms install python3-devel python3